# How to auto-scroll when the page gets too long?

Tags: jquery

I have a simple website, but I have a jquery function when a button is clicked, a list slides down. But I would have to scroll to see the list. How can I have it auto-scroll down when the page gets to long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending the nature of your custom scroll button, perhaps you could implement it as an anchor link which jumps the page to just above the pane it scrolls?

```
<a class="my-scroller" href="#scrollPane">Scroll Down</a>
<div id="scrollPane">
</div>
```

If you are unable to use an `<a href="" />` as your scroll button, you could instead have the click handler for your scroll button also change the page's [location.hash](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0320__Location/Locationhash.htm) value to the ID of your scroll pane.

```
$(".my-scroller").click(function() {
    location.hash = "#scrollPane";
    // scrolling code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an automatic left-to-right scrolling plug-in here: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SmoothDivScroll

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery plugin can be of some use for you: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Answer (score -3):

Let me tell you the best way to auto-scroll a page.

When you visit a microsoft website and when there is an autoscroll it doesn't use any javascript.
The way I am going to tell you is the easiest way in the world to autoscroll a page. Pure HTML.

See the code:

```html
<a href="#thisdiv">Click to scroll</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1 id="thisdiv">HEllo to the scroll page</h1>
```

**Thank you. I hope this would have clarified your doubt. :)**

Comment: This is more a jump than a scroll... Also, it looks like it's the same idea as the first part of the accepted answer.

Comment: It is the same idea but with modern tools. The other one uses JQuery(?). Anyways citation needed for your "best way to scroll" claim.